# Error while assigning conditions to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make operations on an existing dataframe's column, based on other columns of the dataframe.

For example:

```
if (df['col1']== 'this is') & (df['col2'] == 30) & (df['col3'] <= '2020-01-01'):
   df['Value'] = 0
```

Here, I am trying to assign the value 0 to each element of the column `Value` that satifies the conditions in the `if` statement.

However I get the following errror :

> truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: use `numpy.where()` or `pandas.where()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` for better performance:

```
import numpy as np

df['Value'] = np.where(((df['col1']== 'this is') & (df['col2'] == 30) & (df['col3'] <= '2020-01-01')), 0, df['Value'])
```

Comment: In terms of performance (i.e. speed), which one is best `numpy.where()` or `pandas.where()` ?

Comment: Pandas uses `numpy` under the hood. So, numpy should be ideally faster. Though there might not be a considerable performance difference between `np.where` and `df.where`.

Comment: As a new joiner in terms of Python language, that is good information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
mask = ((df['col1']== 'this is') & (df['col2'] == 30) & (df['col3'] <= '2020-01-01'))

df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = 0
```